# How to get a number with unique digits in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: loops, xslt, xslt-1.0, unique, number-formatting

I have below variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="56568"/>
```

Output needed : 568

I need to get a output which contains only unique digits in the number.

Any idea how to achieve this in XSLT 1.0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor? This could be easier if you have access to some extension functions.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 of course you can do `codepoints-to-string(distinct-values(string-to-codepoints($in)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this - unless your processor supports some extension functions. Without it, you would have to use a recursive named template:

```
<xsl:template name="distinct-characters">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:param name="output"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($input)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$output"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($input, 1, 1)" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="distinct-characters">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="output">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$output"/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(contains($output, $char))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
<output>
    <xsl:call-template name="distinct-characters">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="56568"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</output>
```

Result:

```
<output>568</output>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/a9Gix1

---

### Added:

Revisiting this after 4 years, there is a shorter and more efficient way. Instead of iterating over every character in the input, it iterates only over each *distinct* character:

```
<xsl:template name="distinct-characters">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:if test="$input">
        <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($input, 1, 1)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="distinct-characters">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="translate($input, $char, '')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/a9Gix1/1